# Parent/child relationship : how does adoption compare to geirus?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting, mourning-aveilus, yichud-seclusion

Take a father and daughter who both underwent geirus. Now take a Jewish man who adopted a baby girl of unknown (Jewish) parents. In both situations, the father raises the child since birth. Are the halachic aspects of those relationships identical ?

Ideally precise sources will be provided.

Documentation found in other, related posts :
http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/maternity1.html
https://www.shaalvim.org/yeshiva/torah/view.asp?id=661

Comment: The two are absolutely NOT halachically identical. A ger is considered to not have relatives and therefore is eligible to marry anyone other than a Kohen. Your Jewish child of unknown parentage ***might*** be the child of any given Jew and therefore would be significantly more restricted in whom they may marry (assuming no information other than Jewish parentage is known). Regarding your tags, the laws of *aveilus* and *yichud* probably wouldn't be different though.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Thanks for your answer. My question was specifically focused on the parent/child relationship, more than the general status of a ger VS an adopted kid in other areas of their lives. You distinguish in terms of marriage options, is it to say that the geirim could d'oraysa marry, while the adoptive (jewish) father/kid could not ? Or, what's your point ?

Comment: @Lancze There are halachic categories of person labeled "shtuki v'asufi." Shtuki is (generally) where parent is known, while asufi is someone "gathered in" (ne'esaf) from the market place: neither parent is known. The problems here are concerns for a violation of arayos, which is a "safek de'oraisa lechumrah" issue. A ger is not halachically related to ANY one and would be allowed to marry anyone short of a Kohen. Re: your tags, I was stating that in either case the two are not halachically related and thus the laws of yichud and aveilut should be similar.